# jQuery change image when SELECT changes

Tags: php, jquery

**Hello Stackers,**

I'm having a question about jQuery. I have the following code, and I want that if I select one of the options, that the Image SRC changes to that path. (Direct, without any other clicks). Is this possible? (It's a kind of Live Preview of the selected image) I Tried, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**The Form and Image Display**

```
 <b>Afbeelding</b><br><select name="choose" id="choose">
                 <?php
                 if ($handle = opendir('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/magieweb/images/news'))
    {   
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
            {
                continue;
            }   

            echo '<option value="' . $file . '"';

            if (isset($_POST['topstory']) && $_POST['topstory'] == $file)
            {
                echo ' selected';
            }

            echo '>' . $file . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
                   </select><br><br>

                    <ul style="border: 1px solid #2087A1; list-style-type: none; margin-right:40px; min-height:30px;">
            <li><strong style="color:#2087A1; margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px;">Nieuwsafbeelding Preview</strong></li>    
            <li><img id="blah" src=""></li>

         </ul><br><br>
```

**My jQuery**

```
$('#choose').change(function(){
           $('#blah').attr('src', this.value);
            alert(this.value);
        });
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are the rendered paths relative to the path you are currently in ? because that is how the image will try to get loaded from the browser once applied to the `img`.

Comment: A php tag(keyword) for this question is needed!

Comment: What do you mean Gaby? Even when I'm configuring a full path, it won't show the image.

Comment: the browser cannot see the full harddisk path. Its starting path is the root of the website (*and it has no access above that*). So you might need to do something like `echo '<option value="/images/news/' . $file . '"';`

Comment: I agree with @Gaby aka G. Petrioli. For sure it's a path problem.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I Did, but it's still not changing.

Comment: @PascalBoschma you will have to show us the rendered html of the `select` element (*what is produced by your php*). and what is the url of the page you are running. In general the script and logic behind your code is sound, but there might be problems in the overall setup of your website. Is the directory with the images inside the website ?

Comment: `<select name="my_select_box" id="my_select_box">
option value="/magieweb/images/news/bgheader.png">bgheader.png</option></select>`

`<ul style="border: 1px solid #2087A1; list-style-type: none; margin-right:40px; min-height:30px;">
   <li><strong style="color:#2087A1; margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px;">Nieuwsafbeelding Preview</strong></li> 
   <li><img id="my_changing_image" style="width:280px; margin-left:3px;" src="/magieweb/images/news/bgheader.png"></li>
        
         </ul>`

Out of Rights, I had to remove the SITE URL. This is however displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: retrieves selected option value from select box on change.

```js
$('#my_select_box').change(function(){
 $('#my_changing_image').attr('src', $('#my_select_box').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select_box">
<option value="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg">something</option>
<option value="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg">something else</option>
</select>

<img id="my_changing_image" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hqk1r8fk/1/

Comment: I Need to get the SELECTED Option his value.

Comment: @PascalBoschma I updated the snippet to retrieve the value from the select box.

Comment: I've changed my Code, and doublechecked the PATH. It just doesn't change. The Console log doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I Think I found the error. Another Code wasn't correctly closed.